# Import package doesn't work in venv, when executing with python.exe

Tags: python, windows, virtualenv, python-venv

I'm installing package `whl` with `pip` in virtual enviorment.

```
PS C:\Users\Project> .\venv37\Scripts\activate
(venv37) PS C:\Users\Project> pip install .\vtk-9.0.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
Processing c:\users\project\vtk-9.0.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
Installing collected packages: vtk
Successfully installed vtk-9.0.1
```

and import works.

```
(venv37) PS C:\Users\Project> python
Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug  9 2019, 18:34:13) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32

Warning:
This Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the environment has
not been activated.  Libraries may fail to load.  To activate this environment
please see https://conda.io/activation

Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import vtk
>>> exit()
(venv37) PS C:\Users\Project> deactivate
```

Now I try to execute it from Python Interpreter in venv.

```
PS C:\Users\Project> .\venv37\Scripts\activate         
(venv37) PS C:\Users\Project> .\venv37\Scripts\python.exe                                    
Python 3.7.8 (tags/v3.7.8:4b47a5b6ba, Jun 28 2020, 08:53:46) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import vtk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'vtk'
>>>
```

And it doesn't work. What is my mistake?

Comment: I do not think there is a mistake. The two python versions in both examples are different, hence the vtk library is installed for the first interpreter only. Can you post the `ls`command for `.\venv\Scripts` ?

Comment: Use `python -m pip` -- https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/